# jQuery Add button inside a add button function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```js
var counter3 = 1;
$("#addPoll").click(function () {
  if(counter3>5){
    alert("Only 5 Poll is allowed");
    return false;
  } 
  if(counter3==1){
    $("#removePoll").css("visibility","visible");
  }   
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv1' + counter3);

  newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
    '<label>Question '+ counter3 + ' : </label>' + 
    '<input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]"><br></br>' +
    '<input type="button" value="Add Button" id="addPollButton'+counter3+'">'+
    '<input type="button" value="Remove Button" id="removePollButton">' +
    '<div id="TextBoxesGroup3"></div>'+
    //'<label>Number Of Answer : </label> <input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]">' +
    '<br></br><br></br>'
  );

  $("#addPollButton"+counter3).click(function (){
    alert("hahha");
  });

  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");
  counter3++;
});
```

I have a problem here where I would want to add a button to function inside the jQuery. As for my code, I will want to prompt the `alert("hahha");` when the button is clicked but it is not working. Is there a way to overcome this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `$("#addPollButton"+counter3).click(...)`, 0 elements will be matched because the button hasn't been added to the DOM (document) at this stage, so the click handler won't be added to anything. Just define the `.click` *after* the `.appendTo` (or use `$(document).on("click", "#addPollButton"+counter3, function (){ ... });`)

Comment: use event delegation with .on()

Comment: FYI, `$(document.createElement('div'))` === `$('<div>')`

Comment: In fact, `$(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv1' + counter3);` === `$('<div>', {id: 'TextBoxDiv1' + counter3});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use on to delegation but it's simpler just to move one line

```
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1"); // to here

$("#addPollButton"+counter3).click(function (){
  alert("hahha");
});

// from here newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");
counter3++;
```

So that there are elements to match when you define the click event.

Comment: better would be to delegate event to avoid multiple handlers with same logic inside

Comment: There are many things about that particular code that could be better. Simplest route to fix it in this instance.

Comment: I have tried this way, it works but it only work when i do like this $("#addPollButton1") instead of  $("#addPollButton"+counter3) . This shows I get the 1st id only

Comment: @GeneLim my bad, counter3++ was on that line too. That shouldn't move

Comment: What do you meant by it shouldn't move?

Answer (score 2):

well use `on` delegated event for dynamically added elements..change your id to class and and use `on` delegated event

```
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Question '+ counter3 + ' : </label>' + 
        '<input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]"><br></br>' +
        '<input type="button" value="Add Button" class="dynamicAddButton">'+
        '<input type="button" value="Remove Button" id="removePollButton">' +
        '<div id="TextBoxesGroup3"></div>'+
        //'<label>Number Of Answer : </label> <input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]">' +
        '<br></br><br></br>');

       /*you don't need click here.. and should avoid this in any case 
         $("#addPollButton"+counter3).click(function (){
            alert("hahha");
        });*/

      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");counter3++;
 });


$(document).on('click','.dynamicAddButton',function(){
   alert("hahha");
});
```

**NOTE: id should be unique...looks like your code ends up having multiple `removePollButton`  id**

**update..**

if you need id there then you can use attribute selector also..(no need of changing you code)

```
 $(document).on('click','[id^="addPollButton"]',function(){
   alert("hahha");
});
```

and yes please have a look at creating dynamic element in jquery and implement it so you code is more readable (instead of addind a string in DOM )

Comment: +1 but no need to add a class even it is better practice. This will work too: `$(document).on('click','[id^="addPollButton"]',function(){...});`

Comment: yup..:).. but i guess class selector i faster than the attribute selector... anyways.. thanks :) and updated ;).

Comment: I've tried this but when the button is clicked, there is no result as in nothing appears